# Как вывести меню в WorPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть меню которое состоит из рубрик. Нужно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести меню так что если в данной рубрике есть записи то  пункт меню подсвечивается белым и становится активным а если в рубрике нету записей то пункт меню не активный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используй фильтр `nav_menu_css_class`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 3 );
function my_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'header_menu' === $args->theme_location && 'category' === $item->object ) {
        $term = get_term( $item->object_id );
        if ( $term->count ) {
            $classes[] = 'your-class';
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Нужно проверить к какому меню ты будешь это добавлять `'header_menu' === $args->theme_location` и так же проверить, что объект меню является категорией или другой таксономией `'category' === $item->object` и затем проверить, что у термина есть посты `$term->count`.